# Access DB query - need help updating certain records

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I have an access DB which we use to track tickets. Each ticket may have multiple occurrences because of different programming changes associated with that ticket. Each record also has a program_type field which is SVR or VB. Example:

```
123456 - SVR - SomeCode

123456 - VB - SomeVBCode
```

I've added a column to the database called VB_Flag, which defaults to 0, which I would like to change to the number 1 for every ticket containing VB code. So, the result here would be:

```
123456 - SVR - SomeCode - 1

123456 - VB - SomeVBCode - 1
```

But, I can't figure out for the life of me how to write this update query. At first I tried:

```
UPDATE table SET VB_Flag = 1 WHERE program_type = 'VB'
```

But that obviously left out all the SVR code that shared a ticket number with the VB code.

I'm at a loss. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE table SET VB_Flag = 1 
WHERE TicketNum IN (SELECT TicketNum FROM Table WHERE program_type = 'VB')
```

Comment: Thanks! I had played around with the TicketNum IN () stuff but couldn't quite figure it out. This got it!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE tickets SET VB_Flag = 1
WHERE ticket_id IN (SELECT ticket_id FROM tickets WHERE program_type = 'VB');
```

The inner SELECT statement returns a list of all ticket_ids that have a program_type of 'VB'.

The update then sets the VB_Flag to 1 for ALL records with one of those ticket_ids (that includes those with a program_type of 'SVR'.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. You were beaten on the answer but I wanted to let you know this was very helpful as well.

Comment: Glad it was useful.  I figured some explanation of how that sort of nested query works might come in handy down the road.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 
    Table 
    INNER JOIN Table AS Table2
    ON Table.TicketNumber = Table2.TicketNumber
SET 
    Table2.VB_Flag = 1
WHERE 
    (([Table].[program_type]="VB"))

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested select should take care of your problem:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET VB_Flag = 1 
WHERE TicketID in (Select TicketID from myTable WHERE program_type = 'VB')
```